# Postgres SQL not returning expected rows when using the concatenation (||) operator

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, string-concatenation, pgadmin

I have a table with production data, Prod. There are two fields in Prod, A and B, that I use as keys (both of which are VARCHARs). I have another table, Stage, that I want to import into Prod. However, before I import Stage, I want to check whether Stage has rows that are already in Prod. Any duplicate rows are to be excluded from the import.

The problem I have is as follows:

When I run a query such as

```
SELECT A, B 
FROM Stage 
WHERE A || B NOT IN (
    SELECT A || B 
    FROM Prod
)
```

I expect that I will receive a list of all non-duplicate (new) entries. However, I receive no results.

Furthermore, when I run

```
SELECT A, B 
FROM Stage 
WHERE A || B IN (
    SELECT A || B 
    FROM Prod
)
```

where the only difference is changing `NOT IN` to `IN`, I receive only a subset of the table returned instead of what I would expect to be the entire table.

I know the issue has something to do with the concatenation (||) operator because when I run

```
SELECT A 
FROM Stage 
WHERE A NOT IN (
    SELECT A FROM Prod
)
```

rows are returned and the `IN` version of the query returns the remaining rows.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What are the `A` and `B` types in `Stage` and `Prod`?

Comment: You should use `where (a,b) not in (select a,b ...)`. The concatenation can lead to errors because `abc` could mean `a,bc` or `ab,c`. If `a` or `b` can be null then `not in` will not return anything if there is at least one row where one of them is `null`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto A and B are VARCHAR in production as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That works perfectly. Thank you so much. If you want to write it up as answer, I would be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement has two problems:

First: using string concatenation is not going to work as you expect it because the comparison cannot distinguish between the tuples `('a','bc')`  and `('ab','c')` (because both will result in the same concatenated value.

Using a real tuple comparison is the correct way:

```
where (a,b) not in (select a,b ...)
```

Now to the second problem:

A `NOT IN` comparison where the "comparison list" contains `NULL` will always return an empty result because any comparison with `null` yields "unknown" so the database can not reliably decide if the value from the "left hand side" is in that list or not.

You wrote that using: `SELECT A FROM Stage WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM Prod)` returns something, which means that  there are no `null` values in `prod.a` but apparently in `prod.b`.

If you want to ignore the `null` values you can use something like this:

```
select a,b
from stage 
where (a,b) not in (select a,b 
                    from prod
                    where b is not null);
```

Another option would be to treat `null` has something else, e.g. an empty string:

```
select a,b
from stage 
where (a,coalesce(b, '')) not in (select a, coalesce(b, '')
                                  from prod);
```

This problem does not occur when using the `in` operator, so

```
select a,b
from stage 
where (a,b) in (select a,b 
                from prod);
```

is safe to use, even with `null` values.

However if you use those two columns as "keys" you shouldn't allow `null` values in them in the first place.

Btw: this is not something specific to Postgres, this is how SQL in general works.